# delta-v for a trip to Bennu asteroid

Tags: asteroid, hohmann-transfer, near-earth-asteroid

101955 Bennu has a mean diameter of 490 m (1,610 ft; 0.30 mi) and was the target of the OSIRIS-REx sample return mission. What is the delta-v using a Hohmann transfer orbit to do a round trip from low Earth orbit and then to "land" on 101955 Bennu, and then return to Earth, and is it within the SpaceX Starship's range?

I was also going to ask, "How long a duration would be required for such a mission?".  But then I realized the orbital period of 1.1955 years, which leads to a 6.12 year period between consecutive close approaches of Bennu's orbit and Earth's orbit.

Since the asteroid has a longer period then Earth, as do the two Hohmann transfer orbits, one must make (x-1) trips around the sun in (x) years to get back to the Earth ... which I assume is why the OSIRIS-REx mission was a 7 year long mission, which included 3 years at the asteroid....

So the minimum time for an asteroid visiting mission might be much better for an asteroid with about a 2 year period, and might take something like 2.5 years more or less like a mission to Mars using Hohmann transfer orbits.  One can save time using more than the minimum Delta-V for the orbit transfers...

Comment: https://trajbrowser.arc.nasa.gov/traj_browser.php?NEAs=on&NECs=on&chk_maxMag=on&maxMag=25&chk_maxOCC=on&maxOCC=4&chk_target_list=on&target_list=101955+Bennu&mission_class=roundtrip&mission_type=rendezvous&LD1=2020&LD2=2040&maxDT=4.0&DTunit=yrs&maxDV=12.0&min=DV&wdw_width=-1&submit=Search#a_load_results might be informative. Note that the eccentricity of Bennu's orbit means actual transfers are generally quite different from ideal Hohmann transfers.

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff thank you very much!  That information would easily qualify as a complete answer.  There are many 101955 Bennu trajectories that would have a reasonable Delta-V, and some are even a reasonable time mission, where reasonable is about a year.  Earth Departure Mar25 2024, $\Delta V=4.36$, asteroid arrival Oct01-2024, $\Delta V=2.2$, Asteroid departure Oct21; $\Delta V=1.77$ Earth reentry Mar25 2025 at 13.06 km/sec. Total $\Delta V=8.33$

Comment: Starship's $\Delta V$ with 25ktons of cargo is claimed to be 8.30.  From the https://trajbrowser.arc.nasa.gov/traj_browser.php?NEAs=on&NECs=on&chk_maxMag=on&maxMag=25&chk_maxOCC=on&maxOCC=4&chk_target_list=on&target_list=101955+Bennu&mission_class=roundtrip&mission_type=rendezvous&LD1=2020&LD2=2030&maxDT=1.6&DTunit=yrs&maxDV=8&min=DV&wdw_width=-1&submit=Search#a_load_results website; there are some missions less than 1.5 years with a  $\Delta V\approx 7.2$  If @ChristopherJamesHuff wants, he can answer; else wise I'll combine these last three comments into an answer....   Thanks!!!